# How to make ServiceProvider to call Dispose on objects created manually?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (default implementation). I noticed that when I'm adding my object as singleton then `ServiceProvider` ignores `IDisposable` on my object.

```
var instance = new MyDisposableObj();
ServiceLocator.Instance = instance;

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton( instance );
var container = services.BuildServiceProvider();
container.Dispose();
```

Looks like microsoft think that I have to manually dispose objects which are created manually.

But in the case when I do the extension for ServiceCollection I want to encapsulate disposing of my object. I shouldn't force the users of my extension to dispose my object manually!

So, is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: Change what behavior? When do you want the object to be disposed?

Comment: Disposing someone else's singleton would be nice trolling :)... Generally if it is real singleton it would not be possible to get it back to "non-disposed state" without app restart - so I'm not sure why you expect container to take ownership in such case (especially if you can create multiple containers)

Comment: By the way, "_Looks like microsoft think that I have to manually dispose objects which are created manually_" Disposable objects should always be disposed by the code that has (last) ownership of them (exceptions to the rule not withstanding). Do i sense a fundamental misunderstanding of IDisposables here?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov this is my object. I create it and add to ServiceCollection.

Comment: May be I should to manually create ```ServiceDescriptor```?

Comment: How does ```ServiceProvider``` determine whether to call ```Dispose``` or not?

Comment: Coming back here, the problem is that the ServiceProvider is not creating the object, so it's not disposing it.  You should have ServiceProvider create the object, set the ServiceLocator.Instance = services.GetService<MyDisposableObject>() and then let it dispose of the object when it is disposed.  If you create the object, you must Dispose of it.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but maybe it will help to clarify a bit.
You can create object yourself and register using implementation factory. DI will take care of disposing object, as it is taking ownership of it by calling factory method.
It is described in msdn.

```
var instance = new MyDisposableObj();
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton(x => instance);
var container = services.BuildServiceProvider();
container.Dispose();
```

You can verify this with simple unit test

```
[Fact]
public void ServiceProvider_SingletonObjectAddedAsFactory_IsDisposedWithContainer()
{
        // Arrange
        var sc = new ServiceCollection();
        var fake = A.Fake<IDisposable>();
        sc.AddSingleton(x => fake);

        // Act
        var sp = sc.BuildServiceProvider();
        var recieved = sp.GetService<IDisposable>();
        sp.Dispose();

        // Assert
        recieved.Should().NotBeNull();
        A.CallTo(() => fake.Dispose()).MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another option, I think - more proper. Look at ServiceProvider. It implements IDisposable. It means that you should create ServiceProvider by using statement:

using(var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider())
{
var service1 = provider.GetRequiredService();
}

And that's all.